# Using Blas and Lapack libraries in Fortan90 on Linux

Tags: makefile, fortran, gfortran, lapack, blas

I am trying to use the Lapack and Blas libraries in my Fortran90 code on Linux Mint. I believe I have installed both libraries correctly in the following directory: /usr/local/lib
When I compile my code using a makefile I get the error message:

```
gfortran -m64 -O3 -fdefault-real-8 -fdefault-double-8  -c MainHPC2.f90
gfortran -m64  MainHPC2.o Central2Scheme.o Central5Scheme.o     
WriteDataFiles.o  -o P1    
MainHPC2.o: In function `MAIN__':
MainHPC2.f90:(.text+0x2b0): undefined reference to `dgesv_'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
makefile:56: recipe for target 'P1' failed
make: *** [P1] Error 1
```

My Fortran code is simply trying to call a test function:

```
call dgesv(nn,nrhsl,al,ldal,ipivl,xl,ldbl,infol)
```

The makefile I am using is the following:
I believe it is not linking to the libraries properly.

```
FC = gfortran
FFLAGS = -m64 -O3 -fdefault-real-8 -fdefault-double-8 
TARGET_ARCH =
LDFLAGS = -m64 
BLIBS = -L/usr/local/lib -llapack -lblas
EXE = P1

.SUFFIXES:      
.SUFFIXES: .o .f90 .plt

SRC =           \
   MainHPC2.f90  \
   Central2Scheme.f90 \
   Central5Scheme.f90 \
   WriteDataFiles.f90 \



$(OBJECTS):
OBJ = ${SRC:.f90=.o}

$(EXE): $(OBJ)
    $(FC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJ) $(LIBS) -o $(EXE)

%.o  : %.f90 
    $(FC) $(FFLAGS) -c $<

# Define dependencies for modules
# $(OBJ): $(MOD)

clean: 
    rm -f *.mod *~ core
    rm -f *.o
```

Thank you for your help.

Alex

Answer (score 4):

*solution 1*

In your makefile, The sections that compile and link never add the `$(BLIBS)` which contains the BLAS and LAPACK libraries into the linking process.

```
$(EXE): $(OBJ)
    $(FC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJ) $(LIBS) $(BLIBS) -o $(EXE)
```

*solution 2*

or you made a typo and wrote `BLIBS` instead of `LIBS`,

```
LIBS = -L/usr/local/lib -llapack -lblas
```

***note:** This should be more a comment than an answer*